# Dynamically add text to docusign template in C#

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

Is it possible to dynamically add a text value to an existing docusign template ?

I have an existing template that I retrieve from docusign, but I want to customize certain fields based on who I am sending it to.

I have seen text Tabs being used, but in my case it is not succesfull and I am not sure if that only works, when creating the template within the code itself.

```
  EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
            envDef.EmailSubject = "[DocuSign C# SDK] - Please sign this doc";


            TemplateRole tRole = new TemplateRole();
            tRole.Email = "sample@gmail.com";
            tRole.Name = "testing";
            tRole.RoleName = "{ROLE}";
            List<Text> tabsTextList = new List<Text>();


            tRole.Tabs = new Tabs();
            tRole.Tabs.TextTabs = new List<Text>();
            Text textTab = new Text();
            textTab.TabLabel = "Someones Address";
            textTab.Value = userName.Address;
            textTab.XPosition = "100";
            textTab.YPosition = "100";
            tRole.Tabs.TextTabs.Add(textTab);

            List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new List<TemplateRole>() { tRole };

            // add the role to the envelope and assign valid templateId from your account
            envDef.TemplateRoles = rolesList;

            envDef.TemplateId = "***679-987***";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Inbar Gazit, I realized that my role name was not matching what I set from the server side.

```
tRole.Name = "testing";
tRole.RoleName = "{ROLE}"
```

[image]

and the lable had to match as well.

```
textTab.TabLabel = "Someones Address";
```

[image]

Fairly straight forward, just an over site. Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach to do this is to use Composite Templates.
With composite templates, you can mix and match and customize your templates via the API in any way you choose.
This blog post would be a good place to start:

https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-from-the-trenches-composite-templates/ and it has C# code to do something similar, but you can modify it for your needs.

Comment: Seems like the blog is attempting to address the issue but I dont see the additional values and the server template is not being sent

Comment: you can add tabs to the Signer object that you see in the C# code in this blog, a TextTab would be what you want, I think

Comment: or, you can add your text in a document, not a tab, there are a few ways to add text

Comment: I literally copied and pasted and inserted my template id and file but the values dont show.

Comment: you mean the tab values right? you can add them, the code you copy/pasted doesn't do that

Comment: I am referring to the blog you linked (https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-from-the-trenches-composite-templates/ ) which  adds tabs with values  to the signer object. The text Hourly Rate (180.00) does not show up in the doc

Comment: the most likely reason is that the tabLabel doesn't match, but it can also be some other reason. If you download API Logs, these may have some information if you can get the template JSON

Comment: routingOrder must also match, make sure your template and the code has it in both cases.

Comment: Yeah the role name didnt match, didnt realize I had to set it

Comment: great, do you want me to post an answer to this?